# FTDI drivers in Windows for ARM on Parallels VM on M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, parallels, windows-11, arm

I've successfully gotten a Windows VM up and running on Parallels on my M1 MacBook Pro, and it seems to run Intel apps just fine. But now I need to install the FTDI USB-serial VCP drivers, and although the driver installation completes without complaint, the virtual com ports never show up, and the FTDI adapter shows up as an "Other Devices" entry with a warning icon.

Any idea how to proceed, or debug the installation issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same situation and downloaded the driver for Windows ARM and followed this pdf of instructions.
With that I was able to solve it.

I only need to solve the use of an app in c#.net that I have that does not load the FTD2XX.dll file
https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/AN_396-FTDI-Drivers-Installation-Guide-for-Windows-10_11.pdf

You have to perform the installation manually.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to come back to update this question. FTDI were able to give me drivers. There was some pain, as the drivers weren't signed, and for a while every restart required tweaking registry settings, but now it’s working pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that worked for me here, giving the proper credits:
https://forum.parallels.com/threads/ftdi-arm-vcp-driver-questions.357162/

Simply copy your ARM directory from the Mac Folder to the local C: drive in your Windows. Update driver could then find the drivers and install them properly.

Remember you have to "Update Drivers" twice:

1. for the USB Serial Converter
2. For the COM port that will appear after (1) is completed.